# SubString of a string

Tags: c#

I Have a string like filename\34\filename
I just need  the numerical value to separate. 
what can I do?

I used the following code:

```
string versionId = filename.Substring(filename.IndexOf("\\"), filename.LastIndexOf("\\"));
```

I may have the filename with directory name also. If that is the case How can I get the numeric value from that string?

Comment: If the format will always be this, just split and get the value. Else, try a Regex.

Comment: How to split? I tried that also

Comment: Start with MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: *How* did you try to split it, and what went wrong? Additionally, have you tried methods in the `Path` class? And what happens with your current code? Presumably it doesn't work, but what *does* it do? Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, describing the actual and expected output.

Comment: Are you sure that format for all the strings will be `filename\34\filename`? If yes then you can use string manipulations or Regex to pick up numeric value.

Comment: Assuming you want the second string after a '\' which would always be a numerical value, you can use string versionId = filename.Split('\\')[1]; But this is not the solution if problem statement have any specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
string filename=@"filename\34\filename";
string[] lst=filename.Split('\\');
int version=-1;
foreach(var i in lst)
{
    try
    {
        version= int.Parse(i);
    }
    catch{}                
}
Console.WriteLine(version);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, but take care when the input format doesn't match:

```
string filename = @"filename\34\filename";
Console.WriteLine(new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^.*\\(\d*)\\.*$").Match(filename).Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your fileptah will have a static format then sligh modification in your code will give you exact numeric value.

Please note that This solution will work only If you have following file location format:

> **RootDrive\NumeriCvalue\Filename.Extention**

**Test data:**

```
string filePath = @"C:\34\test.txt";
string filePath = @"D:\32344\word.docx";
```

**Code**

```
 string versionId = filePath.Substring(filePath.IndexOf("\\")+1, filePath.LastIndexOf("\\")-3);
```